# React infinite-scroll memory issue arises as the loaded data increases, especially with 20k+ posts containing videos and images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js13, infinite-scroll

This happens when the loaded data gets to about 10000 posts with images/gifs

[image]

X formerly Twitter has the best infinite scroll I've seen so far  I want to implement something similar but my UI has to be a grid so I can't use something like https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window.

I've also tried using [react-intersection-observer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intersection-observer) to only show the elements if the list items are in view which brought the memory usage down quite a bit but it's still using a lot of memory.

[image]

Comment: You should use virtualized list. 
https://tanstack.com/virtual/v3
This is a sample

Comment: Yeah I tried that already it's basically the same thing as https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window, I hate that you have to set a specific width and height to the parent component